# How to add upload profile picture field in woocommerce registration form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a new feature in my woocommerce registration form. I have already added some fields and all are working good. Now, i want add one more field to upload profile picture but failed to do this. 
I have already tried this on functions.php:

```
 add_action('woocommerce_register_form','display_upload_option');
function display_upload_option()
{
    ?> <p><input type="file" name="file-ul" accept="image/*" id="file-ul"></p> <?php
}

 add_action('woocommerce_register_post', 'uploadFile' );
function uploadFile() {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
        $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'file-ul', 0 );
    }
```

When i added this code, one field to upload image is shown and it selects file also but when click on register button,image is not stored anywhere.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need change form enctype to enable user to upload file:

```
//add enctype multipart form to the edit account form
add_action('woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag',function(){echo 'enctype= "multipart/form-data"';});

//Also you need do so for registration form
add_action('woocommerce_register_form_tag',function(){echo 'enctype= "multipart/form-data"';});
```